# Flask-WTF reCAPTCHA ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

Tags: python, recaptcha

I'm using Flask 2.2.5 and Flask-WTF 1.1.1. 
I want to use a Recaptcha field and, get **ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key**
printed on the widget.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, RecaptchaField

class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
  text = StringField("Some text", validators=[DataRequired()])
  recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
  submit = SubmitField("Go")

app.config['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = os.environ.get('RPUB_K')
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = os.environ.get('RPR_K')
```

I'm using Jinja 3.1.2 to render the form

```
{{ render_form(form, novalidate=True, button_map={"submit": "primary"}) }}
```

What is missing/wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

It turns out I had to add 127.0.0.1 to the domains list on the Google reCAPTCHA (v2) admin panel.
[image]

By the way if you add it, you might have to wait up to 30 minutes before it starts working.